# If $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0, 1)$, show that $a + (b − a)U$ is uniform on $(a, b)$.

Tags: probability, statistics

Here is what I understand so far:
[image]

I understand everything so far, however, I am a hit confused at the final steps. How is it that the $P[U<= ((y-a)/(b-a)]$ equals probability function of $U(Fu)$? Moreover, how do $Fu((y-a)/(b-a))$ equal $fy(y)$? What exactly am I missing?

Comment: How did it happen that you don't understand your own attempts at a problem?

Comment: `$P \left[ U \leq \frac{y-a}{b-a} \right]$`, for instance.  Also, `$F_u$`.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I am following a solution manual to a set of practice problems I am doing.

Comment: Then you shouldn't misrepresent someone else's work as your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the blue questions, which is a superset of the questions in your Question, except for "What am I missing?", which is more speculative than one should expect to be answered on the Math Stack.

In $\Bbb{P}\{Y \leq y\}$, $y$ is a real number.  We know the support of the random variable $Y$ is $(a,b)$, so

- for $y \leq a$, $\Bbb{P}\{Y \leq y\} = 0$,
- for $y \in (a,b)$, $\Bbb{P}\{Y \leq y\}$ increases from $0$ to $1$, and
- for $y \geq b$, $\Bbb{P}\{Y \leq y\} = 1$.

That is, this is another way to write a cumulative distribution function.

This also tells us what $F_U$ is.  It is the CDF of $U$ up to $\frac{y-a}{b-a}$.  Notice that

- for $y \leq a$, $\frac{y-a}{b-a} \leq 0$ and the CDF of $U$ up to $y$ is $0$,
- for $y \in (a,b)$, $\frac{y-a}{b-a} \in (0,1) $ and the CDF of $U$ increases from $0$ to $1$ as $y$ increases from $a$ to $b$, and
- for $y \geq b$, $\frac{y-a}{b-a} \geq 1$ and the CDF of $U$ up to $y$ is $1$.

So, just as before, this is the CDF of $U$ up to $\frac{y-a}{b-a}$.

The final equality is just restating what the sequence of equalities (yes, that first "$\implies$" should be an "$=$") starting with "$\Bbb{P}\{Y \leq y\}$" and ending with "$F_U \left( \frac{y-a}{b-a} \right)$" : The CDF of $Y$ up to $y$ is the CDF of $U$ up to $\frac{y-a}{b-a}$.

This "proof" is a little unsatisfactory.  It shows that there is a change of variable taking one CDF (and hence one PDF) to the other.  It does not show that this change of variable has constant derivative, so it does not show that uniformity is preserved.  Of course, the linear function $\frac{y-a}{b-a} = \frac{1}{b-a}y - \frac{a}{b-a}$ has constant derivative, so uniformity is preserved by this change of variable.

An entirely different way to go is to study intervals of width $\delta$ in $(a,b)$ and show that for any choice of $\delta$ and any left endpoint, $x$, such that $(x,x+\delta) \subseteq (a,b)$, the probability in the interval $(x,x+\delta)$ is independent of $x$ (so is uniform).